# Unable to Subscribe to Odometry ROS Message Via Rosbridge

Tags: javascript, json, ros, motion

The aim is for my shape (ie. 'tracker') to emulate the movement of my robot. I have two files for this, one with the rosbridge code to pull the topics from the robot:

```
listener_Odom = new ROSLIB.Topic ({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/odom',
    messageType : 'nav_msgs/Odometry'
});

let odomPosition = {xPos : 0, yPos : 0};
listener_Odom.subscribe('/odom', function(message){
    console.log(`Received message on ${listener_Odom.name} : ${message.data}`);

   let odomPosition = {
        xPos : message.pose.pose.position.x,
        yPos : message.pose.pose.position.y
    } 

    tracker.update(odomPosition);
```

...and, in a separate file sourcing my rosbridge, this piece of code to move the shape in the front-end:

```
tracker = new track(30, 50, "white", 100, 820, 0)
function track(width, height, color, distanceX, distanceY, rotation, odomPosition){ 
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    //this.distanceX = odomPosition.xPos || 0;
    //this.distanceY = odomPosition.yPos || 0;
    this.rotation = rotation || 0;
    this.rotationSpeed = 0;
    console.log("inside track()");

    this.update = function(odomPosition){
        ctx = mainCanvas.ctx1;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(odomPosition.xPos, odomPosition.yPos);
        ctx.rotate(this.rotation); //rotate diagram specified below:
        ctx.fillRect(-this.width/2, -this.height/2, width, height); //first 2 variables ensure that it rotates around its center, and not around origin
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(10,25);
        ctx.lineTo(10,-25);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    this.newPosition = function(){
        this.rotation += this.rotationSpeed;
        this.distanceX += this.speed * Math.cos(this.rotation); //twist with respect to cosine and sine; 
        this.distanceY += this.speed * Math.sin(this.rotation);
    }
}

function moveTracker(){ //recognize keys from keyboard
    mainCanvas.clear();
    tracker.speed = 0; //for linear speed
    tracker.rotationSpeed = 0; //for angular speed
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 37) { //left key; countercl. rotation
        tracker.rotationSpeed = -.1/ (Math.PI);
        rosCmdVel.publish(rosTwistLft);
        //console.log('swinging anticlockwise');
    }
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 38) { //up key
        tracker.speed = 3;
        rosCmdVel.publish(rosTwistFwd);
        //console.log('moving forward');
    }
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 39) { //right key; clockw. rotation
        tracker.rotationSpeed = .1 / (Math.PI);
        rosCmdVel.publish(rosTwistRht);
        //console.log('swinging clockwise');
     }
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 40) { //down key
        tracker.speed= -3;
        rosCmdVel.publish(rosTwistBwd);
        //console.log('moving backward');
    }
    tracker.newPosition();
    //tracker.update();
}
```

- How do I make my front-end file correctly subscribe to the /odom
  topic and move the shape?

edit: I have included entirely the parts of my code relating to movement.

Comment: There's not enough info in your question. Specifically, where is `OdomPosition` declared, and where/how is your `track` method being called?

Comment: @kaliatech Please see the refreshed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is in this code:

```
listener_Odom.subscribe('/odom', function(message){
    console.log(`Received message on ${listener_Odom.name} : ${message.data}`);
    OdomPosition = {
        xPos : message.pose.pose.position.x,
        yPos : message.pose.pose.position.y
    } 
    return OdomPosition;
   }
); // minor: I think this line is missing in your pasted code
```

The subscribe method will call the given callback, so returning OdomPosition from that doesn't really make sense. You could treat OdomPosition as a global variable, which I think is what you might have wanted to do originally. Something like:

```
let OdomPosition = {xPos:0, yPos:0}
listener_Odom.subscribe('/odom', function(message){
      console.log(`Received message on ${listener_Odom.name} : ${message.data}`);
      OdomPosition.xPos : message.pose.pose.position.x
      OdomPosition.yPos : message.pose.pose.position.y
    }
);
```

Note that your current code recreates the object reference on every callback. However, even that has problems because there's no guarantee that the callback will happen *before* you call tracker.update in your `moveTracker` handling.

An alternative for what I *think* you really want to do, is to call `tracker.update` on every odom change. Perhaps something like this:

```
listener_Odom.subscribe('/odom', function(message){
    console.log(`Received message on ${listener_Odom.name} : ${message.data}`);
    let odomPosition = {
        xPos : message.pose.pose.position.x,
        yPos : message.pose.pose.position.y
    } 

    tracker.update(odomPosition)
  }
);
```

And then modify your `tracker.update` method declaration to take odomPosition as a parameter, and remove call to `tracker.update` in your moveTracker method.

Comment: Thank you so much for breaking this down for me. Sadly, I'm still getting the same error: 
    `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xPos' of undefined`   .

Comment: In your updated code, you are still trying to set `this.distanceX` in the constructor, rather than in the `update` method. You are doing so before you've ever declared OdomPosition. Remove the assignment from your constructor, or change it to `this.distanceX = (odomPosition ? odomPosition.xPos : 0)`, or declare odomPosition earlier (which you've currently commented out for some reason).

Comment: Probably more importantly though, it's not clear to me how you intend to use this.distanceX since you are setting it in both `update` and `newPosition`.  One possibility might be to change your update method to something like: `ctx.translate(odomPosition.xPos, odomPosition.yPos);`.  At some point though, it just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm understanding your original comment a lot better now. I have editted my code. The shape has disappeared --probably because I've done something wrong, again--, but the robot is moving now with the arrow keys, which is progess! Thank you for being patient in explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, for the line which you note the error occurs, don't you mean to use the `position` argument you pass in? I'm assuming `OdomPosition` is not a variable in the scope outside of `track()`?

```
this.distanceX = position.xPos || 0;
```

Comment: You're right. I actually had it in my original code, but must have forgot to change it here. I have made edits.